# How to acces Ubuntu files (pictures) from Windows 7

Tags: boot-failure, photography

My Ubuntu is not running, and I can't figure out why or how to fix the problem. It simply won't boot. Although, I can run the Windows 7 so I'm wondering how to access my Ubuntu files by using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use ext2explore for accessing files in a ext formatted partition. You can find the details here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33387/how-to-browse-your-linux-partition-from-windows/